# bootstrap 3 nested rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Because of inherited html parts when using template engines such as twig (PHP) or jinja2 (python), I may need to nest rows like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
        </div>

        ...

        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then should I wrap inner rows in column div like below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or should they be wrappered in container again?

Comment: Nope, no nested containers; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E004

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't wrap the nested rows in `.container` elements, but you *should* nest them in columns. Bootstrap's `row` class has negative left and right margins that are negated by the `col-X` classes' positive left and right margins. If you nest two `row` classes without intermediate `col-X` classes, you get double the negative margins.

This example demonstrates the double negative margins:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- GOOD! Second "row" wrapped in "col" to negate negative margins. -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background: lime;">
            <div class="row">
              Here's my text!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- BAD! Second "row" missing wrapping "col", gets double negative margins -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row" style="background: tomato;">
          Where's my text?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For further reading, [The Subtle Magic Behind Why the Bootstrap 3 Grid Works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) explains the column system in great and interesting detai.

Comment: shouldn't rows always have columns inside of them (rather than a row directly inside another row) due to the negative margin bootstrap gives rows?

Comment: @CatoMinor Yup, you're right. The second example was meant to be anti-pattern demonstrating the double negative margins. I will add a comment to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wrap them in another [container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) - containers are designed for a typical one-page layout. Unless it would look good / work well with your layout, you may want to look into `container-fluid` if you really want to do this.

**tl;dr** don't wrap in another container.